# Using a UNION or UNION ALL on two select statements makes them incredibly slower

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, union

I have two queries, let's call them Query A and Query B.

Both of these queries run in under a second for the scenario I'm testing and Query A returns 1 result, and Query B returns 0 results.

If I union (or union all) these two queries, it takes over a minute to return the (expected) 1 result.

Both queries select the same columns from the same tables. I could potentially rewrite this entire thing without a union by having a highly conditional where clause but I was trying to get away from doing that.

Any ideas? I'm not sure how much of the exact query and schema I can get away with sharing, but I'm happy to provide what I can.

This is on MSSQL 2008 if it matters to anyone's response.

Comment: Can you replicate the result by starting with a new empty schema and adding a small number of tables containing only test data that is not confidential? It doesn't have to be data from your application - just random numbers or a sample database (or data from StackOverflow's data dump, or whatever you like really).

Comment: The database in question used to be running on 2005 until somewhat recently, and I happened to have a copy (with the same data) still running on a 2005 server. The full query (including the union) executes as expected with no additional overhead there. Is there anything specific that changed from 2005 -> 2008 that would cause this that anyone is aware of?

Comment: I was able to replicate on a different 2008 server. I get the problem there regardless of compat level. I didn't figure that would help, but thought it was worth a shot.

Comment: Can you try something? Not sure if it works, so i will not post it as answer yet. Can you try making Query B return 1 or more records and check again?

Comment: @Jay - Are you able to provide a script for us that reproduces the issue? Or at least the queries with table/column names changed so we can see the kind of constructs that you are using. Also what does the `UNION` plan look like compared to the two individual plans? Just a straight forward concatenation operator or does it add any additional spools (for example) for the Union that weren't there when run individually?

Comment: Comparing the execution plans on 2005 and 2008, I do see some differences. 2005 is doing sorts piping into the concatenation that I don't see happening on 2008, although I'm not sure how significant that is. The execution of the full text index searches seems to be  different as well, but that stays the same with or without the union on both 2005 and 2008.

Comment: @Jay - You've obviously hit some edge case and (interested though I am in the outcome) without the plans to look at or any details of the query its a bit of a waste of time us speculating on possible reasons. I would look into `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` to see if the `UNION` plan appears to be doing a lot more work than expected. If that is not the case then look into the waittype DMVs to see if you can figure out what it is spending its time waiting on (wondering if its possible to be an odd full text issue)

Comment: The statistics are definitely different, this line shows up for the union on 2008 but not for either of the queries that are being unioned and not on 2005 even with the union: Table 'fulltext_index_docidmap_637245325'. Scan count 0, logical reads 30744, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Have you tried setting maxdop to 1 and flushing the plan cache?  Can you reproduce this in other environment?

Answer (score 2):

I would try looking at the execution plans within Management Studio for the individual queries, and then compare that to the execution plan for the query containing the UNION.

If there's that drastic of a difference in the execution times, I would imagine that there's something wrong with the execution plan for the UNION'd query.  Identifying what's different will help point you (and maybe us) in the right direction on what the underlying problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The separate clauses in a UNION that are very similar and on the same tables can be merged into one query by the optimiser. You can see this by the lack on UNION operator in the query plan. I've seen similar things before but rarely

What you can do is a `SELECT.. INTO #temp...` for the first query followed by an `INSERT #temp...` for the second

Now, where did I read this...

Answer (score 0):

Are they both doing table scans? It sounds like it might be exceeding cache capacity and you're caching to disk.

Even if they are from the same table the records would probably lock independently.